# Invisible Character

Tags: c#, text

Does anyone know if there is any invisible character in Unicode strings other than the space? Like in windows 98 there were some tricks using ALT+some integer (in fact bugs http://forums.techarena.in/customize-desktop/1121437.htm).
Is it possible to programmatically add some such characters that are not shown by any editor?

Comment: I am working on a proof of concept of Steganography (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). I want to embed some information into text by manipulating some characters that are not readable by normal human eye.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are normally called [Control Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters):

> The control characters U+0000–U+001F and U+007F come from ASCII. Additionally, U+0080–U+009F were used in conjunction with ISO 8859 character sets (among others). They are specified in ISO 6429 and often referred to as C0 and C1 control codes respectively.
>   Most of these characters play no explicit role in Unicode text handling. The characters U+0000 , U+0009  (HT), U+000A  (LF), U+000D  (CR), and U+0085  (CR+LF) are commonly used in text processing as formatting characters.

Comment: One should note, though, that especially the C0 and C1 control codes are in a location where they coincide with normal characters in the Windows codepages. So if your text is not in Unicode but instead one of the ISO-8859 legacy codepages an editor might simply assume a corresponding Windows codepage (e.g. 1252 for Latin 1). Also, some editors also show glyphs for the ASCII control characters (as far as they're not used for formatting).

Answer (score 2):

Unicode provides a set of different space characters that might be used for steganography

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Spaces_in_Unicode

Answer (score -2):

"somestring" + new string(' ',20);

Comment: OP is asking for invisible characters **other than the space**; you are appending 20 space characters to a string.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iFdEcp.  How does this answer the question (which has an accepted answer from 2012)?